# How to DataBind to Combined Data from Multiple Objects?

Tags: c#, database, object, datagrid

my database structure

Car

```
-carid
-carname
-carmodle
-cartypeid
-carmakeid
```

CarType

```
-cartypeid
-cartypename
```

CarMake

```
-carmakeid
-carmakename
```

Basic model for this database would contain same classes
like car,make,type with same properties as the each column of the database table;

What do i do if i want to bind all the data in a datagrid... CarName,CarTypeName,CarMakeName....

what do i do? writing a new class with all the properties in it does no make sense.. u can only Inherit on class so that is not the was... and do i have to change the datalogic layer for that?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches:

1. Expose your nested properties as first-level properties and bind the first level properties to the DataGridview.

   ```
   public class Car
   {
     public int CarID { get; set; }
     public string CarName { get; set; }
     public CarType CarType { get; set; }
     public Make CarMake { get; set; }
     // Expose CarTypeName as first-level property
     public string CarTypeName { get {return CarType.CarTypeName; }}
   }

   public class CarType
   {
     public int CarTypeID { get; set; }
     public string CarTypeName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Implement something similar [to this.](http://www.developer-corner.com/2007/07/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects_18.html)
3. Implement something similar [to this.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ObjectBindingSource.aspx)

Comment: Thank i use this technic but the problem is...when i fetch the data for the database there are a lot of round trips in volved, like her for each row of car i have to one check make and cartype table... which layer do i use to bind these data business logic layer?

Comment: You don't need to make several round trips to read one row of car. You can read a whole car object, including type and make if your select statement does a join to these tables and if your class structure is something similar to the example I gave you. Getting make and type one at a time is tremendously inefficient. Depending on how you implement this, you can have the DAL return a list of cars with all its properties in it.